# SQLiteStudio using upsert

Tags: sqlite, sqlitestudio

I am using Sqlite 3.32.3.  I imported data into a table (rover) with SQLiteStudio 3.2.1.  I want to use UPSERT to update existing rows and insert new rows.  As a test, I'm using the statement below to update a single existing row.  It does not work in the SQLiteStudio sql editor but it does work in the native SQLite3 terminal interface.  I'm using OSX 10.14.6.  Is this a limitation of SQLiteStudio or am I missing something?

INSERT INTO rover ([Employee Number], DeleteDate)
VALUES ('97763','2020-06-24')
ON CONFLICT ([Employee Number])
DO UPDATE SET DeleteDate = excluded.DeleteDate;

Comment: Are you sure this sqlitestudio is using the version of SQLite you think it is?

Comment: I used .version to check the version.  SQLite 3.32.3 2020-06-18 14:00:33

Comment: I just downloaded DBeaver and it works in that GUI.  It's a shame because I like the SQLiteStudio interface the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .version command you used was in terminal infertace and it is version used by terminal binary. SQLiteStudio in version 3.2.1 uses SQLite 3.22.0 on MacOS X, unfortunately (See menu SQLiteStudio -> About -> Environment tab).

That being said, fortunately, you can replace SQLite library file used by SQLtieStudio. Just take `libsqlite3.0.dylib` from your system (or if you maybe compiled your own) and replace the existin one in `SQLiteStudio.app/Contents/Frameworks/`. It's important that the new library has Loadable Extensions compile-time option enabled, cause SQLiteSTudio uses it.

SQLiteStudio 3.2.2 (to be released) will have up to date SQLite.